# how can Linux programmatically reboot from a specified file to support power interruption tolerant upgrades?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

When our remote Linux box boots up, I want it to check for a newer boot file, and reboot that newer file (after first verifying its integrity).

Is there a Linux function that will reboot Linux from a given boot file?
For example:
reboot_function( filepath );
..Where filepath is the path and filename of a Linux boot file, different from the one previously booted.

PURPOSE:
Am trying to create a 100% power interruption tolerant way of upgrading Linux software in the field remotely.  If power dies at any stage of the upload, then when rebooted, the Linux box needs to go back to the last working boot file.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Linux do you have? I don't understand very well but do you want to update all your system, libs, or kernel? This isn't a packing tool responsibility, like apt-get?

## Embedded Linux Boot Process

[Reference](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linuxboot/)

#### Software components Involved in Embedded Linux Boot Process

- Bootloader
- kernel Image
- root file system - either an initrd image or a NFS location

#### Booting process for an Emebedded Systems

- Instead of BIOS you will run program from a fixed location in Flash
- The components involved in the first steps of PC boot process are combined in to a single "boot strap firmware", called "boot loader".
- Bootloader also provides additional features useful for development & debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use kexec to execute a new kernel without having to touch your bootloader configuration.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kexec

Answer (score 1):

Field updates for embedded systems needs to be thought out just a bit.  The most common approach I have run across basically has the following elements:

1. A kernel image that contains the kernel and the associated compressed ramdisk, or cram disk or other file system (which would have the running application) contained with the kernel in a single file image.
2. Two areas (or banks) of flash memory (or other) large enough for this kernel image.
3. A flash sector (or other) dedicated to "boot parameters".
4. Flash sectors (or other) dedicated to a "booter".

The basic idea is that the boot parameters contain current boot bank, while the booter will boot the kernel image resides in that particular bank. During the update process, the backup bank will be written with the newer kernel image.  Then the boot parameters sector can then be updated.  A reset occurs (many methods to do this), and the booter will know to boot the alternate bank.  Note, that the order of updating, or writing to the flash, is critical here.  The boot parameters sector must be written last.

There can be two schools of thought with this.  The first is that one boot bank will never be updated, and contain a solid enough image to at least provide an updated into the update boot bank.

The other idea is that there is a current boot bank and the previous boot bank.  The previous bank will always have the update written into it.

Along with this basic idea, there are several methods to help ensure integrity.  For instance, the kernel images can have a checksum or hash stored in with the boot parameters.  The download process should have similar checking as well.  A check sum on the boot parameters sector helps ensure its integrity as well.

This basic idea can be expanded upon to suite your particular needs.  Remember, write order is very important.